# How to echo selected values on multiselect from database on a multiselect form

Tags: php, mysql

i have a registration form using multiselect which insert options in the value 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 based on selection

However, after inserting i want to provide an option for editing where users edit

and i want the already selected values from database to be preselected while looping other options as unselected

I am experiencing unidentified offset 3, unidentified offset 3........

```
<div class="form-group">
              <label for="touch-spin-1">Course Days</label>
             <select multiple="multiple" name="coursedays[]" style="width: 100%;" data-toggle="select2" data-placeholder="<?php //echo $course_days; ?>" data-allow-clear="true" >
                 <?php                   
                                                                             $entities  = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7";                                             $entity = explode(",",$entities);                                           $servs = explode("," , $course_days);                                                        $arr_length = count($entity);                                                      for($i=0;$i<=$arr_length;$i++){ 
              ?>
                <option <?php if (in_array($servs, $entity)) { echo "selected";} ?>  value="<?php echo $servs[$i]; ?>"> <?php echo $servs[$i]; ?></option>
                   <?php } ?></select></div>
```

Comment: 'not working' isn't much help. Anything in error_log? What's the expected versus actual output?

Comment: Thanks for your interest, the error is ........ unidentified offset 3, unidentified offset 4........

Comment: Ok, so the array $servs does not have a key with array index 3, 4... `var_dump($servs)` and see what it DOES give you

Answer (score 0):

try in this way

```
<?php
            $course_days = "2,3,4";
            $entities = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7";

            $entity = explode(",", $entities);
            $servs = explode(",", $course_days);

            foreach($entity as $en) {
                ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $en; ?>" <?php echo (in_array($en, $servs)) ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>
                <?php echo $en; ?>
            </option>
            <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Woow, it works like magic, thanks so much. One more thing please, how do i assign my option values, like 1 = monday, 2 = tuesday........., instead of my option showing as 1,2,3....it will show as monday, tuesday, wednessday

Comment: build your entities array like this 
$entities = [1 => 'Monday', 2 => 'Tuesday',..]; then foreach ($entity as $key => $en)

Comment: I added $entities = [1 => 'Monday', 2 => 'Tuesday', 3 => 'Wednessday', 4 => 'Thursday' , 5 => 'Friday', 6 => 'Saturday', 7 => 'Sunday' ];  and foreach($entities as $key => $en). Its only submiting as days to database and not as the value and not holding the value

Comment: <option value="<?php echo $key; ?>">